# dotConnect with EntityFramework Core returns Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, dotconnect

I have an application using ASP.Net Core RC2 and Entity Framework Core RC2, and using the dotConnect for Oracle driver (dotConnect doesn't support EF Core 1.0 yet).

I am trying to run 8 GETs concurrently, for different records, and I'm getting this error:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Collection was modified; enumeration operation
>   may not execute.

The exception is thrown from this line of the Get method on the controller:

```
return Ok(_context.Blogs.Include(blog => blog.Posts).FirstOrDefault(blog => blog.Id == id));
```

I have found lots of questions about this subject, but normally the problem is either several threads using the same instance of an object, or modifying the object while iterating, but neither seem to be the case here.

I'm adding the DB context on Startup.cs via dependency injection:

```
services.AddDbContext<BlogsModel.Model>();
```

Each call has its own controller and context instance, I checked by outputting both hashes:

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public IActionResult Get(int id)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{GetHashCode()} - {_context.GetHashCode()}");
    return Ok(_context.Blogs.Include(blog => blog.Posts).FirstOrDefault(blog => blog.Id == id));
}
```

If I remove the Include part, and only get the Blog, it works fine.

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public IActionResult Get(int id)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{GetHashCode()} - {_context.GetHashCode()}");
    return Ok(_context.Blogs.FirstOrDefault(blog => blog.Id == id));
}
```

I also tried an async version but I still get the error:

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public IActionResult Get(int id)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{GetHashCode()} - {_context.GetHashCode()}");
    var task = _context.Blogs.Include(blog => blog.Posts).FirstOrDefaultAsync(blog => blog.Id == id);
    task.Wait();
    return Ok(task.Result);
}
```

The model is very simple:

```
create table BLOGS
(
  id   NUMBER not null,
  name VARCHAR2(200) not null
);
alter table BLOGS
  add constraint PK_BLOGS primary key (ID);

create table POSTS
(
  id      NUMBER not null,
  blog_id NUMBER not null,
  title   VARCHAR2(200) not null,
  content VARCHAR2(500) not null
);

alter table POSTS
  add constraint PK_POSTS primary key (ID);
alter table POSTS
  add constraint FK_POSTS_BLOG foreign key (BLOG_ID)
  references BLOGS (ID);

declare
  blogId number := 0;
  postId number := 0;
begin
  for x in 1..1000 loop
    blogId := blogId + 1;
    insert into blogs values (blogId, 'Blog ' || blogId);
    for x in 1..5 loop
      postId := postId + 1;
      insert into posts values (postId, blogId, 'Post ' || postId, 'Content for post ' || postId);
    end loop;
  end loop;
  commit;
end;
/
```

Full code for the controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using BlogsModel;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace BlogOracle.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class BlogsController : Controller
    {
        private Model _context;

        public BlogsController(Model context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        // GET api/values/5
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public IActionResult Get(int id)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{GetHashCode()} - {_context.GetHashCode()}");
            return Ok(_context.Blogs.Include(blog => blog.Posts).FirstOrDefault(blog => blog.Id == id));
        }
    }
}
```

And the call stack:

```
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(ExceptionResource resource)
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Enumerator.MoveNextRare()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Any[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Expressions.SelectExpression.GetProjectionTypes()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Sql.DefaultQuerySqlGenerator.CreateValueBufferFactory(IRelationalValueBufferFactoryFactory relationalValueBufferFactoryFactory, DbDataReader dataReader)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.NonCapturingLazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized[TParam,TValue](TValue& target, TParam param, Func`2 valueFactory)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.ShaperCommandContext.NotifyReaderCreated(DbDataReader dataReader)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable.Enumerator.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.IncludeCollectionIterator.<GetRelatedValues>d__4.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryBuffer.Include(QueryContext queryContext, Object entity, IReadOnlyList`1 navigationPath, IReadOnlyList`1 relatedEntitiesLoaders, Int32 currentNavigationIndex, Boolean queryStateManager)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryBuffer.Include(QueryContext queryContext, Object entity, IReadOnlyList`1 navigationPath, IReadOnlyList`1 relatedEntitiesLoaders, Boolean queryStateManager)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryMethodProvider.<_Include>d__30`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at lambda_method(Closure , QueryContext )
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.<>c__DisplayClass19_1`1.<CompileQuery>b__1(QueryContext qc)
   at BlogOracle.Controllers.BlogsController.Get(Int32 id) in c:\Projetos\dotnet\BlogOracle\src\BlogOracle\Controllers\BlogsController.cs:line 26
   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
```

The full code is here: https://github.com/ricsmania/BlogsOracleEntityFramework

Am I doing something wrong or this might be a bug with the component?

Comment: Did you every find a solution to this problem?

Comment: @capiono I gave up on dotConnect, the driver was too unstable and the support wasn't helpful at all. Microsoft released a sample driver which seems to be working fine so far: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/tree/dev/samples/OracleProvider